# Valgrind não mostra qual a linha onde ocorreu o erro

Tags: c, valgrind

Estou tentando utilizar o Valgrind para o Linux, a fim de checar perdas de memória, entretanto, o erro mostrado no terminal não exibe em qual linha específica ele está.

==4873==  Address 0x4a4e047 is 0 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd

==4873==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

==4873==    by 0x109221: getName (in /home/rodrigo/Documentos/VsCodeTest/a.out)

==4873==    by 0x1091D5: main (in /home/rodrigo/Documentos/VsCodeTest/a.out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer com que o `valgrind` exiba as linhas, você pode primeiro compilar o programa utilizando o [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) com a flag `-g` que indica para a compilação ser efetuada providenciando informações de debug:

`gcc -g meu_programa.c -o meu_programa`

Quando executar o valgrind, informe a flag `--leak-check` com o valor `full`:

`valgrind --leak-check=full ./meu_programa`

Valgrind deveria exibir mais detalhes sobre o vazamento de memória identificado. Como exemplo, para um programa onde não liberei a memória de um `char*` que havia sido alocada anteriormente, a mensagem abaixo foi exibida no meu terminal:

```
==387== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==387==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==387==    by 0x1091CD: main (practice.c:8)
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.